# Flip Flop not flopping

Tags: flipflop

Haven't used a flip flop since week 2 of uni (well over 20 years ago now) but had a requirement for one in a current project. I need an output that toggles after a button press. Seems like a flip flop is the perfect chip for it.. seems.

My problem is the Q output toggles when the button is pressed, but then toggles back again when the button is released. ie it act as an actual button rather than a flip-flop. Below is an extract of the schematic.

The button is connected via R4/C1 to filter the clock pulse. I've looked on a CRO and it's a nice clean press with no jitter etc. I've changed values of R4/C1 to try both slow and quick ramping, with no difference.

RD is driven high/low by another part of the circuit to enable/reset the flip flop. That seems to work ok.

What am I doing wrong? - Cheers Matt

[image: Flip Flop Extract]

Comment: there is no button switch in the schematic diagram

Comment: You need to provide a **complete** schematic and a link to the manufacturer's datasheet for the exact flip-flop you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your clock transition is too slow. This can be fixed with a Schmitt trigger between the RC circuit and the clock input. https://www.ti.com/lit/wp/slla364a/slla364a.pdf

Comment: I hadn't thought it might be too slow! Just removed the capacitor, no difference, also changed the 1K series to 0R. Still nothing. Have also added a 100K pulldown to GND (button is active high). Then I looked into the schmitt trigger idea. From the datasheet of the 74LVC2G74GS
 "Schmitt-trigger action at all inputs makes the circuit tolerant of slower input rise and fall times." So that's not it.

Comment: @Mutski "Schmitt-trigger action" is not a real Schmitt trigger. Your circuit violates the Δt/ΔV limit in section 9 of the datasheet (and without the capacitor, is bouncing).